# How can I get nested FamilySymbols inside of a family document

Tags: c#, revit-api

If I run this code inside of a project document everything goes perfect, however when inside of a family document, I get an error.

**Code**

```
Document pDoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
FilteredElementCollector fec = new FilteredElementCollector(pDoc);
IList<Element> ec = fec.OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_SpecialityEquipment).ToElements();
```

**ERROR**

***Exception Message***:

> The input argument "document" of function
>   `anonymous-namespace'::FilteredElementCollector_constructor or one
>   item in the collection is null at line 326 of file
>   ...\APIFilteredElementCollectorProxy.cpp.
>
> Parameter name: document

***StackTrace***:

> at ?A0x3fe3c5fb.FilteredElementCollectorProxy_constructor(Document document)
>
> at Autodesk.Revit.DB.FilteredElementCollector..ctor(Document document)
>
> at `myNamespace`.`myExternalCommandName`.Execute(UIApplication uiapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real culprit was wrapping my head around the ExternalEvents once again. It really had nothing to do with the logic of this code.

Answer (score 1):

The `uiapp.ActiveUIDocument` is the active project document.

You need something different for a family, unless the family **IS** the currently active document.

If the project document is currently active and the family has been loaded into it, you can use the `EditFamily` method to retrieve a `Document` instance for the family document.

The Building Coder provides a number of examples for this in the topic groups on the [Family API](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.25) and [Loading a Family](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.25.3).

Comment: The family .rfa file document **IS** the ONLY active document, in my test case.

Comment: Nevermind me, after grappling with the code, I just realized that this was just the initial pass that I was blaming, turns out I was running the same exact code from a raised event, and I needed to turn my pDoc into a Globally accessible variable reference, to come back into the same context, because of the nesting. I failed to contextually move my pDoc to the Family Document (even though I thought by default this would be the same **I was dead wrong**, I needed to go the extra step and move the variable scope to treat it as the Project as you mentioned). Sorry for the trouble.